# Graphical transformation handles in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graphics, gtk, image-manipulation, cairo

I am experimenting with creating GUI and graphics based applications in Haskell using gtk2hs and cairo. Currently I am working on a program where a user can create and manipulate simple geometric shapes on screen.

The three manipulations I want the user to be able to do are: translation, rotation and scaling. The ideal implementation of this would have the transformation handles present in most image manipulation programs such as photoshop:

[image]

(i.e Where the object can be translated by dragging somewhere inside it, scaled by dragging the appropriate white box, and rotated by clicking and dragging in the direction of rotation outside of the object's box)

I cannot find a simple way of doing this "out-of-the-box" in either the gtk or cairo documentation, and have been unable to find a suitable library by searching on google. Does anyone know of a Haskell API which would allow me to manipulate graphics in this way or, failing that, know how I would go about implementing my own version of this type of functionality in Haskell?

Answer (score 1):

There are not built-in widgets for this; you'll have to build it yourself by drawing all the appropriate elements (e.g. the actual shape, a bounding box or similar, rectangles on the corners and edges of the bounding bex, etc.) and handling mouse events by checking whether the events fall on these elements or not. It should not be difficult... though it may be a bit tedious.